# elasticsearch curator delete "all" indices order than 7 days

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

background:

```
elasticsearch version 6.2
curator version 5.4.1.
```

Now I can use curator to delete one index that order 7 days, but I have more than one index and I don't want to create more than one action.yml, such as :

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
        Delete indices older than 7 days (based on index name), for student-prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      disable_action: False
    filters:
        - filtertype: pattern
          kind: prefix
          value: student=
        - filtertype: age
          source: name
          direction: older
          timestring: '%Y-%m-%d'
          unit: days
          unit_count: 7
```

According to this action.yml, It deletes student=2017-XX-XX.
But I have many indices such as teacher, parent and so on.
I replace studnet= with *= but doesn't work.

So what can I do?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You try a few things. A few examples include:

1. You can omit the `pattern` filtertype, leaving only the `age`.  This might delete other indices with `%Y-%m-%d` patterns, however.  In that case, you might use a different `pattern` filter, but to [*exclude*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.4/fe_exclude.html) patterns you don't want to delete:

       `- filtertype: pattern
         kind: prefix
         value: omit_me
         exclude: true`
    Replacing your `pattern` filter with this will delete all indices with `%Y-%m-%d` that are older than 7 days, *except* indices starting with `omit_me`.
2. You might set up a [`regex`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.4/filtertype_pattern.html#_regex) instead of a [`prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.4/filtertype_pattern.html#_prefix). For example:

       `- filtertype: pattern
         kind: regex
         value: '^(student|parent|teacher).*$'`
    This will match indices starting with `student`, `parent`, or `teacher`.